# Displaying UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I'm trying to displaying an image from file on my ViewController in Xcode. I have in my ViewController.h:

```
UIImageView *image;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImage* image ;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image 
{
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nameoffile.jpg"]];

    self.image = image;

    [image release];
}
```

But no luck. It won't let me link my UIImage instance in the xib.

Comment: You should create UIImageView instance in xib, which would already contain necessary image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `UIImageView` is created when the NIB file is loaded, there is no need to make it an instance variable, so remove it from your header file:

<strike>UIImageView *image;</strike>

Next ensure that your `UIImageView` outlet is actually connected correctly to the image view within the NIB file. You will see a filled circle when it is connected (this is from a *Beginning iOS Development* example, which uses ARC, so ignore the `weak` keyword):

[image]

And finally you should be able to set the image view's image in the `viewDidLoad` method (there is no need to use an instance variable for the `UIImage` either, as it will be retained within the `UIImageView`):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameoffile.jpg"];
}
```

Comment: @AndreaF You don't need variables for either the `UIImageView` or `UIImage`.  The image view is within the NIB, so you just want a connection to it (`IBOutlet`) and nothing more and the `UIImage` is retained as part of the image view, so there is no need to store it as instance variable.

Comment: @trojanfoe he is making IBOutlet for UIImage not for UIImageView . UIImage cant be connected to the UIImageView in the NIB

Comment: @DushyantSingh I don't understand what you mean.  My suggestion is to connect an `UIImageView` outlet to the NIB, not an `UIImage`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one.You know you can't get IBOutlet on UIImage. So you need to write UIImageView instead of UIImage.

```
  @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView* image ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Error of your code.

```
 @property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImage* image ;

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image 
{
   _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
  _imageView.frame=self.view.frame;
  [self.view addSubView:_imageView];

    [image release];
}
```

Comment: Thank you but not sure about loading the file.   _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_image:@"file.jpg"];

Comment: imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"file.jpg"]];